# join two simple arrays into two dimentioanl array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I was trying to develop a function where I provide two simple arrays of same size and it covert it into two dimentional array,but so far no success

Here what I did

```
$list1=array(78,79,80,81);
$list2=array(1,2,3,4);

$result=joinArray($list1,$list2);


function joinArray($array1,$array2){ 
  $Jarray=array();
  for ($x=0; $x<=sizeof($array1)-1; $x++) {
   $Jarray[]=array($array1[$x],$array2[$x]);

  }
  return $Jarray;
}
```

I want the end result should look like this

> ```
> $result[0][0]=78
> $result[0][1]=1
> $result[1][0]=79
> $result[1][1]=2
> $result[2][0]=80
> $result[2][1]=3
> $result[3][0]=81
> $result[3][1]=4
> ```

But its not retuning array in this format,Please tell me why its not working what is the proper way of doing it

Thanks

Comment: I think you are 1 array level too deep -> `$Jarray[]=array($array1[$x],$array2[$x]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple code:

```
function joinArray($arr1, $arr2)  {
    $final_array = array();
    $row = 0;
    for($x = 0; $x<count($arr1); $x++){
        $final_array[$row][0] = $arr1[$x];
        $final_array[$row][1] = $arr2[$x];
        $row++;
    }
    return $final_array;
}

$list1=array(78,79,80,81);
$list2=array(1,2,3,4);
$result = joinArray($list1,$list2);
```

The $row variable do the trick.

Comment: thanks , why use additional var $row ,it works fine without it

Answer (score 1):

You're adding an extra level to the array.

Replace this:

```
$Jarray[]=array(array($array1[$x],$array2[$x]));
```

with this:

```
$Jarray[]=array($array1[$x],$array2[$x]);
```

Comment: @khurram4m what is the problem? the code works correctly [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/218a72b8263a4a82b52cc7167dc99bda032b9e4e)

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic return your required output

```
$list1=array(78,79,80,81);
$list2=array(1,2,3,4);
$array = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($list1);$i++)
{
$array[$i][0] = $list1[$i];
}
for ($i=0;$i<count($list2);$i++)
{
$array[$i][1] = $list2[$i];
}
var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => int 78
      1 => int 1
  1 => 
    array
      0 => int 79
      1 => int 2
  2 => 
    array
      0 => int 80
      1 => int 3
  3 => 
    array
      0 => int 81
      1 => int 4
```